# Datagridview data that is shown is different from the data that the datagriview has

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, serial-port

I have one main form(form1) that among other things it waits to receive info

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim output As String
    output = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
    Converter(output) 'format what was received
    Submit() 'submit into db
    Form3.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

and process/submit the information into the db and if the form3 is open (that condition is not tested yet but all the times i do test i make sure to open form3 before send data through the serial port) it should update the datagridview in form3.

```
Public Class Form3
        Delegate Sub dgvDelegate()
        Sub fill()
            tabela_dispensa.Rows.Clear()
            Conectar(conn, myCommand) ' connect to db
            myCommand.CommandText = "select dispensa.*,produto.Descrição from dispensa join produto on dispensa.PLU = produto.PLU"
            result = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            While result.Read
                tabela_dispensa.Rows.Add(result(0), result(5), result(1), result(2), result(3), result(4))
            End While
            Desconectar(conn) ' disconnect from db
        End Sub
        Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
            'Conectar(conn, myCommand)
            'myCommand.CommandText = "select dispensa.*,produto.Descrição from dispensa join produto on dispensa.PLU = produto.PLU"
            'result = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            'While result.Read
            '    tabela_dispensa.Rows.Add(result(0), result(5), result(1), result(2), result(3), result(4))
            'End While
            'Desconectar(conn)
        End Sub

        Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
            If InvokeRequired Then
                Invoke(New dgvDelegate(AddressOf fill))
            Else
                fill()
            End If
        End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that datagridview only changes when form3 is loaded.

I have runned some tests and i could see that after openning the form3 when i receive data the datagridview loses all rows before i do something even so the datagridview looking is the same even losing data what's weird.

So if someone could help me update the datagridview would be great but I would be just as happy if someone could only help me understand why the datagridview loses all data but what is shown remains like nothing happend.

Important:
Datagridview as no databound.

Sorry if the text its a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try including these when you fill the datagrid (replace DataGridView1 with whatever yours is called)

```
        DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        Application.DoEvents()
```

Comment: Same ,there are no difference

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me..

```
Dim command As String
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
Dim ds As New DataSet
Try
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(conString)
    command = "Your SQL Query"
    connection.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command, connection)
    connection.Close()
    ds.Tables.Add("ProductDetails")
    da.Fill(ds, "ProductDetails")
End Using
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("ProductDetails")
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
Application.DoEvents()
```

Comment: I have tried and didn't work anyway i don't think its something with my connection to db cause as i said when the form loads it calls the fill function and it works properly just dont work when the SerialPort1.DataReceived event on form1 call the backgroundworker